# want to take only one input between 2 input field from html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have 2 input in html form. stock in and stock out. In form submission it send st_in and st_out to server with request.
I want-
*if two value(stock_in + stock_out) is submitted system should through error.
*If no value submitted(stock_in + stock_out) system should through error.
*Either "stock in" or "stock out" value should submit then the save method will store the data.

```
 public function stock_record(Request $request){
        $stock=new Transection;
        $stock->in=$request->st_in;
        $stock->out=$request->st_out;
        $stock->product_id=$request->st_name;
        $stock->barcode=$request->barcode;
        $stock->description=$request->st_description;
        $stock->user_id=Auth::id();
        $stock->save();
        return redirect('dashboard')->with('message',"Transection successfully updated");
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public function stock_record(Request $request){

if($request->st_in == null && $request->st_out == null)
{ 
return back()->withError('Error ...');
}

if($request->has('st_in') && $request->has('st_out'))
{
return back()->withError('Error ...');
} else if($request->has('st_in') || $request->has('st_out))
{
        $stock=new Transection;
        $stock->in=$request->st_in ?? null;
        $stock->out=$request->st_out ?? null;
        $stock->product_id=$request->st_name;
        $stock->barcode=$request->barcode;
        $stock->description=$request->st_description;
        $stock->user_id=Auth::id();
        $stock->save();
        return redirect('dashboard')->with('message',"Transection successfully updated");
    }
}
```

Comment: if($request->has('st_in') && $request->has('st_out'))
        {
            return back()->with('message', "both filled");
        }


This is giving feed back "both filled". but I just put data in one field. it should return error when both are filled

Answer (score 0):

It's working Now

public function stock_record(Request $request)
{

```
    if ($request->st_in == null && $request->st_out == null) {

       return back()->with('message', "you didn't either fill stock in or out");
    }
```

//correction Here
if ($request->st_in > 0 && $request->st_out > 0) {
return back()->with('message', "Error, You cannot fill both stock in and out at a time")
//